# Getting null.bin file after sharing a video in whatsapp from my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have stored a video file in the android raw folder and want to share it through WhatsApp. But I am getting the file in WhatsApp as null.bin.

```
 private void shareVideo(){

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/video_name");
    
        Intent videoshare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        videoshare.setType("*/*");
        videoshare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  uri);
        startActivity(videoshare);

    }
```

Comment: Since `ACTION_SEND` is not supposed to use `android.resource://` `Uri` values, the fact that you get anything at all is pure luck. And, since you are not providing the actual MIME type of the content, I am uncertain what you are expecting any app to do with it. You might want to switch to using a `ContentProvider` and a concrete MIME type (instead of `*/*`).

Comment: How can I do it, can you please give me a link?

Comment: FWIW, I cover `ContentProvider` in "Content Provider Theory" and "Content Provider Implementation Patterns" of [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/). There is also material on `ContentProvider` [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating).